# How to use angularjs translate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-translate

I have two questions.

1)How to use angularjs translate with ng-repeat ?

I have Json file and all text is working but with ng-repeat not.
My fragment in json :

```
  "rules":{
     "points":[
        {"text":"1"},
        {"text":"2"},
        {"text":"3"}
     ]
  }
```

I tried to write something like this and it doesn't work:

```
<ul ng-repeat="rule in 'rules.points' ">
    <li >{{rule.text | translate}}</li>
</ul>
```

2) How to use angularjs translate with src and href?

Can somebody give me some exaple?

Comment: i just ask how to rewrite and wrote about my wrong code,lol)

Answer (score 0):

**Possible problem #1: Wrong Translation Key**

Check if translation key in your translations.json file is exactly the same as in rule.text

**Possible problem #2: Translations are not loaded in time**

"translate" in {{key | translate}} is filter and filters are synchronous. It means, that translation key from your translations.json (or whichever source you are using) file may be not loaded by the time filter finishes executing. Try this (async way) instead:

```
<li translate="{{rule.text}}"></li>
```

or

```
<li><span translate="{{rule.text}}"></span></li>
```

Comment: i tried this,but something is going wrong.In my view, something with ng-repeat is wrong.In console i have mistake in anugularjs lib,so it means that it is some discommunication with anuglarjs and ths variat of solution.

Comment: Instead of writing all this you could write text of the error :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all this is pretty pointless, if you really mean translations.

What you are trying to use is a pipe in Angular 2 or 4. So you should have something like this:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
   @Pipe ({
   name : 'translate'
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(val : string) : string {
       // number check...
       return (parseInt(val) + 10) + '';
   }
}
```

I assume this should work, if the class is known by your component. Usually pipes are in their own module, so make sure the pipe is exported correctly there.

Your second question:

I consider it best practice to move the logical parts of pipes to static methods in another class like 'PipeFunctions.ts'.

Something like

```
export class PipeFunctions {
    static translate(val : string) : string {
       return (parseInt(val) + 10) + '';
   }
}
```

Now the translation might be used by the pipe as well as by a component. Just implement a proxy method in your xyz.component.ts like

```
translate(val : string) : string {
    return PipeFunctions.translate(val);
}
```

Then in your corresponding HTML:

```
<a href="translate('1')">whatever</a>
```

If it does not work (sorry, can't check it out here), try

```
<a [href]="translate('1')">whatever</a>
```

or even

```
<a [attr.href]="translate('1')">whatever</a>
```